# How can I perform a reset on the loop I have when pressing a button?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm creating a code where 3 balls will bounce when a button is clicked. I have a code I found in the internet and added the start button but clicking it multiple times speed up the balls. Also, I tried adding a reset button that will clear out the canvas but can't make it work. Sharing both the HTML and JS code.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width = 1000;
const height = canvas.height = 500;
ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

function random(min, max) {
  const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return num;
}

function Ball(x, y, velX, velY, color, size) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.velX = velX;
  this.velY = velY;
  this.color = color;
  this.size = size;
}
Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}
Ball.prototype.update = function() {
  if ((this.x + this.size) >= width) {
    this.velX = -(this.velX);
  }
  if ((this.x - this.size) <= 0) {
    this.velX = -(this.velX);
  }
  if ((this.y + this.size) >= height) {
    this.velY = -(this.velY);
  }
  if ((this.y - this.size) <= 0) {
    this.velY = -(this.velY);
  }
  this.x += this.velX;
  this.y += this.velY;
}
let balls = [];

function loop() {
  while (balls.length < 3) {
    let size = 35;
    let ball = new Ball(
      random(0 + size, width - size), random(0 + size, height - size), 5, 5, 'yellow', size);
    balls.push(ball);
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].draw();
    balls[i].update();
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

document.getElementById('Begin').addEventListener('click',loop);
```

```html
<input type='button' id='Begin' value='start'>
<canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: balls=[] inside your click event, your loop depends entireley on balls array hence you need to empty it

Comment: I don't quite follow. So, should I put the balls=[] in my Begin function? Sorry, just new to this and not fully familiar with terms, etc.

Comment: what is the name of your "press button function"

Comment: `const canvas = document.querySelector('myCanvas');` is wrong. EITHER `const canvas = document.querySelector('#myCanvas');` or clearer: `const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');` - I fixed it and made you a snippet

Comment: code is:
<input type='button' id='Begin' value='start'>

Comment: I also added an eventListener to your button to get things started. If you hide the button after clicking it, you will not run faster

Comment: is there a way to retain the button but upon clicking again won't have me go faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the requestAnimationFrame in a var and use cancelAnimationFrame to stop

I added a div to hold the buttons and now delegate from that div so only one event handler is needed.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width = 1000;
const height = canvas.height = 500;
ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
let rq; // this we can use to request and cancel


function random(min, max) {
  const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return num;
}

function Ball(x, y, velX, velY, color, size) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.velX = velX;
  this.velY = velY;
  this.color = color;
  this.size = size;
}
Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}
Ball.prototype.update = function() {
  if ((this.x + this.size) >= width) {
    this.velX = -(this.velX);
  }
  if ((this.x - this.size) <= 0) {
    this.velX = -(this.velX);
  }
  if ((this.y + this.size) >= height) {
    this.velY = -(this.velY);
  }
  if ((this.y - this.size) <= 0) {
    this.velY = -(this.velY);
  }
  this.x += this.velX;
  this.y += this.velY;
}
let balls = [];

function loop() {
  while (balls.length < 3) {
    let size = 35;
    let ball = new Ball(
      random(0 + size, width - size), random(0 + size, height - size), 5, 5, 'yellow', size);
    balls.push(ball);
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].draw();
    balls[i].update();
  }
  rq = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

document.getElementById('butDiv').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.id === "Begin") {
    if (tgt.value === "start") {
      loop()
      tgt.value = "stop";
      document.getElementById("resetCanvas").classList.add("hide");
    } else {
      cancelAnimationFrame(rq)
      this.value = "start";
      document.getElementById("resetCanvas").classList.remove("hide");
    }
  } else if (tgt.id === "resetCanvas") {
    cancelAnimationFrame(rq)
    ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    document.getElementById("Begin").value="start";
    tgt.classList.add("hide");
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="butDiv">
  <input type='button' id='Begin' value='start'> <input type='button' class="hide" id='resetCanvas' value='reset'>
</div>
<canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: It worked! Now the animation stops when it's clicked. Last question though, would it be possible to add another button that will allow the canvas to start from scratch (just the blank canvas)?

Comment: See update. I had to add a delegation and a div to hold the buttons

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much, just gotta fix the style and all good.